# Magento2 which table to store data like configurable product

Tags: magento2, database, configurable-product, simple-product, associate-products

Magento2 which table to store data like configurable product and associated related simple product and also in Magento1 which table to store data like configurable product and associated related simple product

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

**Main table for products in magento:**

**catalog_product_entity**

> Above table is an act as main table, for that child tables are staring
>   with “`catalog_product_entity_`” prefix.

```
- catalog_product_entity_datetime – Product – date attribute are stored here. Ex: New From, New To
- catalog_product_entity_decimal – Product price related values.
- catalog_product_entity_gallery
- catalog_product_entity_int – Product Status, Visiblity etc..
- catalog_product_entity_media_gallery – product images path, Thumb , small, etc
- catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value – Product image,product image position,  title info & position of image info, etc
- catalog_product_entity_tier_price – Product tier product
- catalog_product_entity_varchar – Product name, URL, etc
```

**Configurable product** information will get it from below tables

```
- catalog_product_super_attribute
- catalog_product_super_attribute_label
- catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing
- catalog_product_super_link
```

Comment: good bit of info. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check this table which is using for Configurable product

```
catalog_product_super_attribute
catalog_product_super_attribute_label
catalog_product_super_link: it contains associated simple product of configurable product
catalog_product_relation
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1) in Magento 2 "catalog_product_relation", "catalog_product_super_link", "catalog_product_super_attribute_label" and catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing  will store the information about the configurable product and associated related simple product.

2) sorry, I have no Idea about Magento 1.X